# Many IPs from different Subnets and Gateway to one machine

Tags: linux, shell-script, centos, networking, kvm

I use CentOS 7.1 and I have more then two IPs attached to one machine, which is on Cloud (KVM). The IPs are from different Subnets and Gateways. To work all I must delete all "ip route" saves, except the first, which is the Gateway on eth0.  To be more clear I will post some examples.

"ip route" output:

```
default via 31.171.x.1 dev eth0  proto static  metric 100 
default via 185.12.x.1 dev eth1  proto static  metric 101 
31.171.x.0/22 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 31.171.x.185  metric 100 
178.22.x.149 via 185.12.x.1 dev eth1  proto dhcp  metric 100 
185.12.x.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 185.12.x.172  metric 100
```

To work both IPs I should delete the last 4 lines and the output to be only:

```
default via 31.171.x.1 dev eth0  proto static  metric 100
```

"ifcfg-eth0" config:

```
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
ONBOOT=yes
```

My idea is to make some script or change the file "ifup-routes", because is very annoying every time when I reboot my machine or up/down the interface I must delete routes line by line. It's not a option to configure static interface.

Comment: I don't have EL7 but on EL6 I believe I solved a similar problem to this using `PEERROUTES=no` in *ifcfg-ethX* files. Not an exact solution and I don't think well documented, except in the network scripts themselves, but I think if you analyze the scripts you will find config vars to get the behavior you need - or something close to it.

Comment: Actually it isn't working..